# Javascript Simple check for webform to make sure it contains both numbers and letters (instead of my code)

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
if(address.length<=0)
{
msg.setAttribute("style", "color:red");
  msg.innerHTML='Please enter address';
  return false;
}
```

I would like to change so it checks whether the webform contains BOTH numbers and letters. Can you help me?

Thank you so much,
Jones

p.s.: So I want to make sure they also enter street name AND house number as well (example: 24 Sunshine street would be good, but if they forget house number, they would get the message).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't look like PHP at all. More like JavaScript...
Here's one way to do it in JavaScript:

```
var re = /^\d+\s+\D+$/;
if (re.test(address)) {
    //We get here if the address is correctly formated
}
else {
    //We get here if the string is badly formated
}
```

The regex works like this:

- \d+ matches to one or more numbers
- \s+ matches to one or more spaces
- \D+ matches to one or more letters

If you want to accept both "24 Sunshine" and "Sunshine 24" you could instead use this:

```
/^(\d+\s+\D+)|(\D+\s+\d+)$/
```

And if we want to be extra safe and protect from the case that the user might enter an extra trailing or leading space we could either trail the string or use this ReGex:

```
/^\s*(\d+\s+\D+)|(\D+\s+\d+)\s*$/
```

Comment: Hi!!! You're so right, my mistake! I corrected the title now. Thanks, I'll test it right away. I hope even I'll be able to implement it. Thanks

Comment: You're the best, this code is perfect!! Thank you so-so much, you've just made my day!

Comment: Is there a way to simply make it so it check whether it contains both numbers and letters? Because sometimes we have addresses like this: Blk 610 Sunshine Road or they add a dot at the end of the number Sunshie Road 24.

Comment: @AidynJones Well, if you remove the '^' and '$' it will look for a string of numbers and letters, but it wont care about anything else (aka there could be a dot in the end).
The ^ and $ matches with the end and beginning of your string, and is therefore a bit more 'strict' than what you want :)

Comment: Yes, thank you! Got everyting. You've been of great help to me, truly appreciate it!

Kindest Regards,
Jones

Comment: @AidynJones Glad I could help! :D (please do upvote comments/answers that was useful :P )

Answer (score 0):

Apart from regular expression which is a very nice and clear solution you can use these php functions:

first the [ctype_alnum ()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php) in order to check if your string contains letters and digits and then 
this on [ctype_alpha()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php) in case the above is true to check if user forgot to enter number. 
In case you are interested there is also this one [ctype_digit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) for checking if user missed the address but gave the number.

Or if you want just a regex this it will do the job:

```
 ^[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z-]+\s)+\d{1,4}
```